# Formatting layout from java in android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I want to create a list of items.Each list item should have four text in it. And all of the four will placed at different four corner of that list. I can do in xml file. But I can not figure out how can I do it from java in android. Because I need to create those list from my database. For your better understanding my problem following is my xml code.Please can anyone help me.. ?

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tvb"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Left Aligned"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Right Aligned" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Left Aligned" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Right Aligned" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok! So what's the problem?

Comment: I suggest using a single RelativeLayout instead of deeply nested LinearLayouts like this. It would be much easier to read and would likely improve the app's performance.

Comment: thank you very much @Tanis.7x . But it would be more helpful if can give me some sample java code to get that... :D

Comment: @exponentialFun: Why do you need to create the layout in Java? What's wrong with the XML layout?

Comment: because the list will be dynamic @Darwind

Comment: If only the content (i.e. the text in the four TextViews) is changing, then you can still define the layout in XML but change the text in Java.

Comment: @exponentialFun as Tanis.7x said. Even if your layout changes you can just define different XML layout for each item in the `ListView` if you like and then dependent on the data change the layout. I'll post an example if you'd like.

Comment: yeah please post your example. May be it will help me writing some efficient code. I am waiting for your example for using them in my project @Darwind

Comment: @exponentialFun posted an example/answer to your question. I really recommend sticking with the XML layout - it's much easier to navigate and customise to your needs in comparison to creating the layouts in pure Java code - In my opinion :-)

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your example. However you recommended sticking with the XML layout . I also prefer that. And I already have done that using xml. But problem is that My list contains about 30 items . So listing them all together my xml file gets too lengthy. So I thought it is not that wise (mya be ). Getting xml too long... is it really problem, i mean is it really inefficient. What you think @Darwind. If you say it is not that inefficient I will stick to xml.. cause handling that way is much easier for me.

Comment: @exponentialFun if you have 30 different items, that don't at all look like each other, you'd have to create 30 different XML files. However if the items, are almost the same you could inflate the same layout file for all items, and then use `if-else` statements to hide and show different elements in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have a look at this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

A comprehensive guide to `ListView`s in general and how to create your own custom `Adapter`s.

Now when you've looked at this you might want to have a look at your `getView` method of your custom `Adapter`, because this is where all the fun is ;-)

The `getView` method is called for each `ListView` item in your list.

This is where you inflate your XML layout and set the texts of your layout file.

An example of how the `getView` method could look like, could be this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myrowlayout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
    TextView textView4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview4);

    // Set the text of the textViews accordingly to where you are in the list.
    // An example
    if(position % 2 == 0) {
        // If even position in the list, set the first TextView
        textView1.setText("This text is only shown for even positions in your list");            
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

You could also look at the `Collection` you have supplied to the `Adapter` in the first place and see if there is any special items, that you want to apply a specific layout to.

This can also be applied to specific screensizes for instance - Tablets should use a `GridView` instead of a `ListView` for instance (in most cases).

Off topic: My code example is by no means efficient for loading items. If you want efficient code, you should have a look at the [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) for instance.

Hope this helps you along the way :-)